# NVDA unable to review landmarks on a webpage

Tags: accessibility

I have to fix up a website to make it more accessible.  Someone said my webpage is missing the `main` landmark.  To confirm this, he said to download NVDA software, open up the NVDA software, then navigate to my website, then press `Insert F7` to open up the Elements List which should look like this:

[image]

But when I press `Insert F7`, my browser gives me this pop up instead:

[image]

Does anyone know how to use NVDA to open up elements list to reveal my landmarks?

Answer (score 1):

Try pressing the FN or function key along with insert F7.
This will likely bring up the Elements List for NVDA. You can also peruse the landmarks on a webpage with NVDA by pressing the 'd' key, the landmark shortcut key.

Comment: My keyboard has these two buttons: 
Button 1: [Fast Forward OR Function + F7]  &&
Button 2: [Insert OR Function F12]

If I press Function+ Insert + F7, my browser thinks I'm pressing F7 and F12 together.

I have 4 other keyboards in my house all with similar problem, where the Insert button also has a Function <some other key> button.   What other options exist to get the Elements List?